# GDB: How to list all source files used for compilation

Tags: debugging, gdb, ddd-debugger

New to the project, have multiple source files used for compilation and some "could" be dynamic libraries, loaded at runtime. When debugging the executable using "GDB", is there a command to list all the source files (static) used to build the executable. Once I have all the source files, it's easy for me to set breakpoints, list functions etc. I couldn't find a command to do it in GDB (I'm sure there should be one). In DDD (gui based gdb), there is a Menu: File->List, which lists all the source files used and static libraries used for building the executable. Unfortunately, for command line based debugger (GDB), I couldnt find an equivalent command.

Answer (score 81):

You are probably looking for `info sources`. `info functions` could also be helpful.

Don't forget you can do things like type `break` and then just press tab, which will list all relevant functions.

Comment: "info sources" works. I wish there is a way to filter the source files, as it shows tons of C/C++ libraries

Comment: There is a way to grep this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41965454/gdb-grep-info-sources-files