# GDB grep info sources files

Tags: gdb

Is it possible to grep or filter the output of info sources in gdb?
Something like:

```
(gdb) info sources | grep bob.cpp
```

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Is it possible to grep or filter the output of info sources in gdb?

**Update:**

Yes. As of commit [ae60f04e08bf](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=commit;h=ae60f04e08bf) (GDB version 9 and above) `info sources` can accept regexp and other arguments. From `help info sources`:

```
All source files in the program or those matching REGEXP.
Usage: info sources [OPTION]... [REGEXP]
By default, REGEXP is used to match anywhere in the filename.

Options:
  -dirname
    Show only the files having a dirname matching REGEXP.

  -basename
    Show only the files having a basename matching REGEXP.
```

**Stale previous answer:**

No. This could be considered a bug: `info shared` takes an optional regex to filter shared libraries, but `info sources` does not.

Workaround:

```
(gdb) set logging on  # GDB output will now be copied into gdb.txt
(gdb) info sources
(gdb) set logging off
(gdb) shell grep bob.cpp gdb.txt
(gdb) shell rm gdb.txt
```

If you need to do this often, you could put above commands into a [user-defined command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html).

Comment: is there a way to log to gdb.txt without scrolling through the entire list of files? Once I quit from scrolling through `info sources`, gdb stops logging in `gdb.txt`.