# get only source files created by user in GDB

Tags: c, gdb

Is there any GDB command I can use that will show only source file created by user. I mean no source files belonging to libraries like stdio,string and etc.
If I use the *info sources* I will receive all the files used in project, i want only files I create i.e. main file and files I include using #include "someFile.c".
and not files included using <>

for example if I have:
main.c, otherFile.c, otherFile.h

and the main has:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "otherFile.h"
```

when i ask for source files i will see only:
main.c, otherFile.h, otherFile.c

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably not in straight `gdb`. But, IIRC, you can write a python program that binds to (e.g.) `libgdb` and you can write whatever custom interface/command you want. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482869/invoke-and-control-gdb-from-python

Comment: If you can construct a regex for your sources, you can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/41965636/72178.